# Weird assertDatabaseMissing Behavior

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I have a weird behavior for `assertDatabaseMissing`.  I am using spatie permission and I am trying to build UI and API for it.

I have the similar test for permission but it's working well. For the roles CRUD test is a bit weird.

Here is the link of the video

https://youtu.be/UjnbivluGfI

Comment: `assertDatabaseMissing` is a helper of `Laravel` https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database-testing

Comment: Please can you show the code you have that's displaying the weird behaviour. Would you also be able to explain what you mean by weird behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

`Model::toArray()` includes [the relations](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1172) of your model too. Use [`Model::attributesToArray()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L121) instead to get only attributes.

```
$this->assertDatabaseMissing('roles', $role->attributesToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks @Dan. I haven't thought of the relationship. My first time to encounter this method also.